# Show that $\mathbb P_\mu(A) = \int \mu(\mathrm dx) P_{\delta_x} (A)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

It is known that for sufficiently "nice" space $S$, and a transition kernel $p$ on $S$: the consistent collection of finite dimensional distribution defined by
$$\mathbb P_n(X_0\in B_0,\cdots,X_n\in B_n)=\int_{B_0}\mu(\mathrm dx_0)\int_{B_1}p(x_0,\mathrm dx_1)\cdots\int_{B_n}p(x_{n-},\mathrm dx_n)$$
may be extended to a probability measure $\mathbb P_\mu $ on $S^{\mathbb{N}}$.

> I would like to show that
>   $$\mathbb P_\mu(A) = \int \mu(\mathrm dx) P_{\delta_x}(A),$$
>   where $\mathbb P_x $ are the measures introduced similarly from
>   $$\mathbb P_n(X_0 \in B_0, \cdots, X_n \in B_n) = \int_{B_0} \delta_x(\mathrm dx_0) \int_{B_1} p(x_0, \mathrm dx_1) \cdots \int_{B_n}  p(x_{n-1}, \mathrm dx_n).$$
>   That is for each $x$ we have changed the initial distribution from $\mu$ to the point mass $\delta_x$, and then we integrate those new probabilities of $A$ over $x$ with respect to $\mu$.

---

Would it be sufficient to show that for any $n $ and any $B_0, \cdots, B_n$,
$$\int_{B_0} \mu(\mathrm dx_0) \int_{B_1} p(x_0, \mathrm dx_1) \cdots \int_{B_n} p(x_{n-1}, \mathrm dx_n)\\
= \int \mu(\mathrm dx) \int_{B_0} \delta_x(\mathrm dx_0) \int_{B_1} p(x_0, \mathrm dx_1) \cdots \int_{B_n} p(x_{n-1}, \mathrm dx_n)?$$

Much grateful for any help provided!

> EDIT: I see that I haven't written anything about the sequence $(X_n) $ above. I believe if we want the first equation to hold we may take $(X_n)$ to be some kind of canonical process?

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient, and it can be proved by Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: @Saad Could you expand a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$Suppose the σ-algebra associated with $S$ is $\mathscr{S}$, then for any $B_0, \cdots, B_n \in \mathscr{S}$,\begin{align*}
&\peq \int_S μ(\d x) \int_{B_0} δ_x(x_0) \,\d x_0 \int_{B_1} p(x_0, \d x_1) \cdots \int_{B_n} p(x_{n - 1}, \d x_n)\\
&= \int_S μ(\d x) \int_S \left( \int_{B_1} p(x_0, \d x_1) \cdots \int_{B_n} p(x_{n - 1}, \d x_n) \right) I_{B_0}(x_0) δ_x(x_0) \,\d x_0\\
&= \int_S μ(\d x) \left( \int_{B_1} p(x, \d x_1) \cdots \int_{B_n} p(x_{n - 1}, \d x_n) \right) I_{B_0}(x)\\
&= \int_{B_0} μ(\d x) \int_{B_1} p(x, \d x_1) \cdots \int_{B_n} p(x_{n - 1}, \d x_n),
\end{align*}
which implies$$
P_μ(A) = \int_S μ(\d x) P_x(A). \quad \forall A \in \mathscr{S}^{\mathbb{N}}
$$

Comment: Thank you! So basically what you have used is the fact that for any real valued function $f $, the Dirac measure is such that $\int f(x_0) \delta_x(d \, x_0) = f(x) $? Then since the "measurable rectangles" (sets of the form $B_0 \times \cdots \times B_n $) determine any measure on $S^n $, the (finite dimensional) measures generated by the two different way of integrating are equal. The last step is that by Ionescu-Tulcea,  the measure on $S^\mathbb N $ is uniqely determined by the "consistency" condition and thus the extended measures from the two different way of integrating must be equal.

Comment: Did I get that correct?

Comment: @MrFranzén (1) Yes, that's the definition of Dirac measure. (2) Yes, but I only knew the name is “Kolmogorov’s extension theorem” instead of Ionescu-Tulcea. Thanks for making me know more names :)